# Serialization by group fails for Embeddables

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I am trying to use groups to make only parts of `MyEntity` be serialized when I call:

```
$myEntities = $repository->findAll();

return $this->json([
            'myEntities' => $myEntities
        ], 200, [], ['groups' => 'main']);
```

in one of my controllers' routes (to avoid circular reference-error). But I am having trouble making it work with embeddables.

To get a simplified look on the situation, see:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MyEntity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Embedded(class="App\Entity\Util\MyTestEmbeddable")
     * @Groups("main")
     */
    protected MyTestEmbeddable $test;
}
```

with

```
/**
 * @ORM\Embeddable
 */
class MyTestEmbeddable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private string $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private string $text2;

}
```

But the results only contain empty arrays for the `MyEntity::$test`  property.

I would have expected for MyTestEmbeddable::$text`and`MyTestEmbeddable::$text2` to be serialized as well.

What do I need to do to make it work as I expected?

Comment: That works indeed! Damn...that's something I could have thought of -_- Though I must say it bothers me that I can't pass this triggering behaviour down from the using entity. I mean that kinda makes it necessary to stick to this naming-convention in any class that might be using such an embeddable. Nevertheless you solved the immediate problem, so if you post it as an answer I will gladly accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the serialization group not only for the `MyEntity::$test`, but for the individual properties of `MyTestEmbeddable` you want to be part of the serialization group.

E.g.:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 * @Groups("main")
 */
private ?string $text;
```

This way you can choose which individual properties of the embedded entity are going to be serialized.